# Issue with firebase_app_distribution ang GithubActions

Tags: android, github-actions, fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

I am using `fastlane` and `GithubActions` to build and distribute android builds (`firebase_app_distribution`).
From the local machine, all works fine, but when I run the CI, it fails with the next error:

[image]

Github workflow runs on `ubuntu-latest`.

Any ideas on how to fix this?